# Clone multiple USB drives at once

Tags: usb, clone

I need to clone about 1>100usb drives. Is there any tool or way to clone a few at a time.
Thank you

Comment: I see you got down voted for this, it might be better in future if you put in your question the research you've carried out prior to asking along with the solutions you've tried that haven't worked.  You should also always put in your OS.

Comment: The tool that you want is called a [USB Duplicator](http://www.aleratec.com/usb-duplicator.html). There are many vendors -- ask Google for more.  If you want to do this on the cheap, [Lawrence's advice](http://serverfault.com/a/554078/32986) plus a bunch of USB hubs plugged in to a cheap Linux box will also do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone 1 use to many other USB sticks ?
I would use `dd` on linux for that.
Create the image from the USB stick onto your hard drive
`dd if=/dev/sdb of=/tmp/usb.img bs=1M`
And then once that is finished, you can then plug in the USB sticks and clone from the image
`dd if=/tmp/usb.img of=/dev/sdb`
`dd if=/tmp/usb.img of=/dev/sdc`
`dd if=/tmp/usb.img of=/dev/sdd`
`dd if=/tmp/usb.img of=/dev/sde`

etc.